# Terraform resource always recreated

Tags: terraform, openstack

Terraform (v0.11.14) always recreate resource *openstack_compute_instance_v2* ... *security groups* even if nothing has changed.

Provider.openstack is v1.20.0

Below is tfplan(~ update in-place always):

```
  ~ openstack_compute_instance_v2.test
      security_groups.#:         "0" => "1"
      security_groups.867065656: "" => "d5f370f6-c292-4366-9a47-9f040daa5393"
```

It`s also visble in terraform.tfstate: *"security_groups.#": "0",*

Snippet from code:

```
  security_groups = [
    "${data.openstack_networking_secgroup_v2.sg-ssh-test.id}",
  ]
```

I`ve tried it also with *sg-ssh-test.name* without success.

Expected result is that no change is detected.

Comment: Does your OpenStack instance actually have a security group attached? It looks like Terraform is trying to set the security group, OpenStack accepts it, and then when Terraform refreshes the state it can't see it being set.

Comment: Yes, directly via web console I see it attached to VM

Comment: Is that the entire plan output for the resource?

Comment: Yes, all other resources are correctly created, updated, destroyed, but only security_groups has zero indication

Comment: When I use _security_group_ids_ inside of "openstack_networking_port_v2" it works correctly and then map it as **network port** inside of "openstack_compute_instance_v2"